# How to stop the disclosureIndicator from move the cells background image

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom TV cell that has a background image. The problem is that when I show a disclosureIndicator it pushes the background image over and I get a white area where the disclosureIndicator is. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
theCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your image to the cell, not the cell's content view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean to the UITableViewCell controller? If so I'm not sure how to do that. can you please point me in the right direction?